# Working with shell command strings in vim's system() function

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to write simple function which runs a shell command and prints the result into vims shell output window, this here is a basic version of the function which does work:
function defined in `~/.vimrc`

```
function! Runphp()
    let s:runphp='cat /tmp/php_snippet | php'
    echo(system(s:runphp))
endfunction
```

file /tmp/php_snippet

```
<?php
$a = ['apple', 'orange', 'bannana', 'pear'];
print_r($a);
```

If I run `:call Runphp()` vim prints the result of the executed PHP in the result window, all good.
The problem occurs where the `<?php` tag doesn't already exist in `/tmp/php_snippet` i.e.

file /tmp/php_snippet looks like this:

```
$a = ['apple', 'orange', 'bannana', 'pear'];
print_r($a);
```

and I try to inject `<?php` as part of the shell command, i.e.

```
function! Runphp()
    let s:runphp='{ echo "<?php"; cat /tmp/php_snippet } | php'
    echo(system(s:runphp))
endfunction
```

If I `:call Runphp()` now, vim returns

> Error detected while processing function Runphp:
>   line    3:
>   E484: Can't open file /tmp/vReTqKG/9

How can I deal with this error so I can get this extra `<?php` injected into the shell command?

Comment: Brace-enclosed compound commands are supposed to end with either a newline or a semicolon before the closing brace.

Comment: @muru  nice spotting! your knowledge always impresses me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
Compound Commands
   A compound command is one of the following:
   ...
   { list; }
          list  is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list
          must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This  is  known
          as  a  group  command.
```

Note: in `{ echo "<?php"; cat /tmp/php_snippet } | php`, you need a `;` before the closing brace. Unless you're using zsh, in which case the whole thing would have worked fine.

The output from bash isn't particularly helpful:

```
$ bash -c '{ echo "<?php"; cat /tmp/php_snippet } | php'  
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

However, I can find no way to get `system` to return even this error message, without manually calling `bash -c`.

Comment: Yes it would be interesting if vim use reliably use zsh. I'm assuming - but could be wrong - that the shell vim uses for `system()` is based on what you have set as your default shell for your UNIX system account. When I have set zsh as default, I have experienced errors in vimdiff so I keep the system shell as bash - then run `exec zsh` at the end of `.bashrc` so vim continues to use bash and I get zsh at prompt. it takes a bit longer to start shell but its workable

Comment: Odd, I have never experienced any problems in Vimdiff (my shell is zsh across Ubuntu and Arch Linux systems). Probably a bug fixed in newer Vims.

Comment: I used to get the errors on Ubuntu 14.04 when using vimdiff as `git difftool`. I am now running 16.04 with vim-gtk from pi-rho repo and I just tested changing the shell to zsh. It's now worse, errors in  core vim and more errors in vimdiff. e.g. when running `git difftool`- `"includes-shared/vim/user_setup_commands.sh" [readonly] 310L, 9093C/usr/bin/zsh: can't open input file: globstar
/usr/bin/zsh: can't open input file: globstar

E810: Cannot read or write temp files
E97: Cannot create diffs
`

Comment: @the_velour_fog O.o no errors on 14.04 or 16.04. How did you set zsh as your shell?

Comment: added `set shell=/bin/bash` into `~/.vimrc` seems to have fixed it. so now zsh is the default vim uses bash. I got the idea after searching and finding this <https://coderwall.com/p/lzf7ig/using-vim-with-fish-shell>

Comment: I set zsh as the default for my UNIX account by running command `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` - then log out and log back in.